# Curve_fit of real and imaginary data

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I have an array of x-data of length 640 with just real data, and an array of y-data of length 640 where each value has a real and imaginary part. I used the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50203979/11776116), where I define the yBoth as:

```
yBoth = np.hstack([np.real(ydata),  np.imag(ydata)])
```

where `np.real(ydata)` and `np.imag(ydata)` both has length of 640 when I executed:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
def drag_fit_func(x, A, S, t, B):
    return A*np.exp(((x - t/2)/2*S)**2) + 1j*B*(A*((x - t/2)/S**2)*np.exp(((x - t/2)/2*S)**2))

def funcBoth(x, A, S, t, B):
    N = len(x)
    x_real = x[:N//2]
    x_imag = x[N//2:]
    y_real = np.real(drag_fit_func(x_real, A, S, t, B))
    y_imag = np.imag(drag_fit_func(x_imag, A, S, t, B))
    return np.hstack([y_real, y_imag])

yBoth = np.hstack([np.real(ydata),  np.imag(ydata)])
poptBoth, pcovBoth = curve_fit(funcBoth, xdata, yBoth)

print(poptBoth)
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (640,) (1280,)
```

How can I overcome this problem?

And thank you.

Comment: Is this a typo? `I print(poptBoth)`

Comment: @L.Clarkson no, it is not a typo I did execute:  'print(poptBoth)',  then I got the error.

Comment: Ah, right that's from the question you linked, I thought you were printing the yBoth array

Comment: Yes :) I want the poptBoth values

Comment: This is because the x data has 640 points but the yBoth list has twice as many elements as x data 1280 (each y data element has real and imaginary values, hence twice the number of values). Duplicating the x data would certainly stop the error, but I don't know if that would give you the right curve_fit behaviour.

Comment: I enlarge the xdata to length 1280 which solved the error, but `print(poptBoth)` returns an array `[1. 1. 1. 1.] `, which I don't think they are the right values of the variables for fitting my data.

Comment: Hi @L.Clarkson I added the code that I'm executing, perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISTM the least-squares problem is that you are simultaneously fitting real and imaginary parts of the data to real and imag parts of the model function. 
(Arguably) the most direct way then is to use least_squares and provide the cost function which returns the array of residuals.

EDIT: here's a near-duplicate: [Least squares in a set of equations with optimize.leastsq() (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664199/least-squares-in-a-set-of-equations-with-optimize-leastsq-python)

Comment: Thank you @ev-br! Actually I didn't get the full idea, could you please elaborate more with some code if possible? I appreciate your help :)